# QNX Target connection lost

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I'm using Momentics IDE to create a QNX virtual machine (with virtualbox) on my Ubuntu 20.04 host machine.

I edited the networks settings of the vm, choosing a bridged adapter, with the `Promiscous Mode` set to `allow all`.

I can ping my vm from the terminal and I can ping my host from the vm.

My problem is that in Momentics the VM Target has the status `connection lost`, making me unable to use Momentics's features for pushing my app on the target and debug it with a visual interface.

What could be the problem, seeing how I clearly have connection between the host and target, because the pings work.

I should mention that I have the same setup under a windows host and there the connection works without issues.